# Where to fuse high voltage batteries connected in series?

Tags: batteries, short-circuit, fuses, circuit-protection

I have modules of cells in series each with 48V.

I wonder where is the right place to fuse the modules in series. (The current to trip the fuse is the same on every point).

**Version 1:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPFkEO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Version 2:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqTIuq.png)</sup>

**Version 3:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5yduj.png)</sup>

Version 1 is the usual one, what points against the other two versions?

---

There is a difference with a grounded battery for sure:
[image]
source: [link](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-12/fuses/)

Comment: Physical accessability of the fuse (version 2 is probably going to be buried in between the batteries somewhere), and disconnecting of the ground if that matters in your system

Comment: The fuse's function is to **break the circuit** when too much current flows. It can perform that function in **any** location in the circuit so in that respect it does not matter where the fuse is. What matters more is physical location of the fuse (easy to replace or maybe you actually want to prevent that!).

Comment: What is your fuse trying to protect? This may seem an irrelevant question but it might be important. Most fuses protect cabling infrastructure from burning; what's your reason for a fuse?

Comment: Take an EV as an example environment for this this installation. Every possible case it can be usfull as an extra protection. To stop the current flow of a short or damaged wire it can be placed at any point in the row I guess. Are there other circumstances that demand the fuse at a special locatione (Version 1,2,3)?

Comment: Think of a fuse as a normal wire. When there's too much current flowing through the fuse, it'll effectively snap like a rope, and will create a discontinuous state. Your three "versions" will behave differently so I don't agree with you when you say "...it can be placed at any point in the row I guess..."

Comment: It totally depends on the terminals being accessable. If all nodes in the circuit are accessable by unqualified personal and there is a possibility they will interact, location **does** matter, and probably 1 fuse is not enough... And for the same reason it is sometimes preferred the fuse is **inaccessable**.

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose of these modules is to be 'modular', that is they can be removed, replaced, handled separately, then one fuse per module, to protect each module, would seem to be a good investment.

If the load wiring requires tighter protection than the modules do, then put a further fuse in series with the wiring. The normal expected place for such a fuse would be next to a contactor, just to avoid surprising people.

While there is no difference between the three locations as far as breaking the current is concerned, the second option does result in lower voltages remaining after a fault opens the fuse. 48v is still rated 'touch safe' whereas 96v is not. Whether your post-fault fault-finding instructions would ever allow you to make safe use of that small advantage is another matter.